# How to display EnumProperty control like radio buttons, while keeping the selection exclusive?

Tags: python, scripting, interface, properties

I have an `EnumProperty` set up on the Scene in the register function:

```
def register():
    bpy.types.Scene.my_enum = bpy.props.EnumProperty(
        name = "My enum",
        description = "My enum description",
        items = [
            ("FIRST" , "First one" , "Description..."),
            ("SECNOD", "Second one", "Some other description")
        ]
    )
```

Now, elsewhere in the code I have a *Panel*, which is to display the 'enum' for selection:

```
class SomePanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_idname      = "some_panel"
    bl_label       = "A panel"
    bl_space_type  = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context     = "render"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        scene = context.scene
        layout.prop(scene, "my_enum")
```

So far so good, the control draws correctly, but not the way I want:

[image: Enum dropdown]

---

Thing is - I wanted a different appearance - I didn't want a dropdown field, instead I want a radio-button like field, as the one found for example here:

[image]

... where I can choose one of the options regarding the color mode (*BW* , *RGB* or *RGBA*).

I've found that I can put the `"ENUM_FLAG"` in the options field of the `EnumProperty` definition:

```
def register():
        bpy.types.Scene.my_enum = bpy.props.EnumProperty(
            name = "My enum",
            description = "My enum description",
            items = [
                ("FIRST" , "First one" , "Description..."),
                ("SECNOD", "Second one", "Some other description")
            ],
            options = {"ENUM_FLAG"}
        )
```

This too worked fine, the result I got now is this:

[image]

But now I can activate both buttons at once using <kbd>Shift</kbd>, and that's what I want to avoid:

[image]

So **How can make the selection exclusive?** How to force Blender to switch from one option to the other (or in other words: How to disable the <kbd>Shift</kbd> functionality)?

Comment: I struggle with the title of this question, it seems to me it should include " giving visibility to all items at once" (like a radio button array).

Comment: @zeffii Perhaps it could sound this way, but I've considered putting all the context in the title to be an overkill.

Comment: @zeffii Is it better now?

Comment: Remove the `options = {'ENUM_FLAG'}` to remove multi-select. You can then set a default.,, eg default='FIRST',

Comment: @luke1985 I don't know if there's a 'better', only time and upvotes will tell. I agree context-overkill could happen, but if you don't mention `options={'ENUM_FLAG'}` then non-exclusivity isn't even in the realm of possibilities for the enum. hence my thoughts about the title.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Booleans have `toggle=True`, and Enums have `expand=True`

```
layout.prop(scene, "my_enum", expand=True)
```

[image]

The most extensive [UI cookbook is still this one](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:2.5/Py/Scripts/Cookbook/Code_snippets/Interface) though [the layout docs](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_76_2/bpy.types.UILayout.html?#bpy.types.UILayout.prop) are definitely useful after you've struggled a little. Other than those two sources I find it best to read through the `draw` functions of the add-ons supplied with Blender (you probably did this already.. if not, do)

Comment: Almost all UI layout that you can interact with is described in Python, so if you see a UI feature you like dig through its source.

Comment: Oh, thanks for that link - for now I've been using only the official reference guide and this site plus the existing addons source (and to be honest with you, I already found the answer while writing the question - in the netrender addon source - but I wanted to share the knowledge for such a, hopefully, common case).