# Do something when check/uncheck checkbox Python

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I have a checkbox in my addon and I wonder how I can I execute or run some code when checking and unchecking it. I found this [link](https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?294796-How-to-run-code-when-user-toggles-my-checkbox-(or-other-UI-element-Callbacks-)&p=2391307&viewfull=1#post2391307) but I tried following the given answer there (as shown below) but it is not working, nothing happens when I check/uncheck the checkbox.

This is my script:

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "tester",
    "description": "",
}

import bpy
import os
from bpy.props import (StringProperty,
                       BoolProperty,
                       IntProperty,
                       FloatProperty,
                       FloatVectorProperty,
                       EnumProperty,
                       PointerProperty,
                       )
from bpy.types import (Panel,
                       Operator,
                       AddonPreferences,
                       PropertyGroup,
                       )

class MySettings(PropertyGroup):

    my_bool = BoolProperty(
        name="Enable or Disable",
        description="A bool property",
        default = False
        )

class UV_OT_my_panel(Panel):
    bl_idname = "UV_OT_my_panel"
    bl_label = "My Tool"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"   
    bl_region_type = "TOOLS"    
    bl_category = "Tools"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        scene = context.scene
        mytool = scene.my_tool

        # display the properties
        layout.prop(mytool, "my_bool", text="Bool Property")
        layout.prop(mytool, "my_int", text="Integer Property")
        layout.prop(mytool, "my_float", text="Float Property")

        # check if bool property is enabled
        if (mytool.my_bool == True):
            print ("Property Enabled")
#           bpy.data.objects['Cube'].hide = True

        else:
            print ("Property Disabled")
#           bpy.data.objects['Cube'].hide = False

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)
    bpy.types.Scene.my_tool = PointerProperty(type=MySettings)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__)
    del bpy.types.Scene.my_tool

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
os.system('cls')
def my_prop_callback(self, context):
    if context.scene.my_prop:
        #pass # do something here if user checks checkbox (but not uncheck, just as an example)
        print('Enteredddddddddddddddddddddddddd')
        if context.scene.mytool.my_bool == True:
            bpy.data.objects['Cube'].hide = True
        else:
            bpy.data.objects['Cube'].hide = False    

bpy.types.Scene.my_prop = bpy.props.BoolProperty(update=my_prop_callback)
```

Comment: Related http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/43727/15543  you cannot set id_data in the draw method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

actually your code is running... but you must open your blender with the cmd (console)

[image: open blender in console]

after that you can see the prints in the cmd

[image: cmd]

**/**** update**

you should check [enter link description here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35007/how-can-i-add-a-checkbox-in-the-tools-ui)

I clean the code....

[image: properties]

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "tester",
    "description": "",
}

import bpy

from bpy.props import (StringProperty,
                       BoolProperty,
                       IntProperty,
                       FloatProperty,
                       FloatVectorProperty,
                       EnumProperty,
                       PointerProperty,
                       )
from bpy.types import (Panel,
                       Operator,
                       AddonPreferences,
                       PropertyGroup,
                       )


# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    store properties in the active scene
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
def update_func(self, context):
    for obj in bpy.data.objects:
        if (self.my_bool == True):
            #print ("Property Enabled")
            obj.hide = True
        else:
            #print ("Property Disabled")
            a = obj.hide=False
            print(a)
def update_func_1(self, context):
    for obj in bpy.data.objects:
        if (self.my_bool1 == True and obj.name=="Cube"):
            print ("Property Enabled")
            obj.hide = True
        else:
            print ("Property Disabled")
            obj.hide = False

class MySettings(PropertyGroup):

    my_bool = BoolProperty(
        name="Enable or Disable",
        description="A bool property",
        default = False,
        update = update_func
        )
    my_bool1 = BoolProperty(
        name="Enable or Disable",
        description="A bool property",
        default = False,
        update = update_func_1
        )
    my_int = IntProperty(
        name = "Set a value",
        description="A integer property",
        default = 23,
        min = 10,
        max = 100
        )

    my_float = FloatProperty(
        name = "Set a value",
        description = "A float property",
        default = 23.7,
        min = 0.01,
        max = 30.0
        )

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    myTool in the image editor
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------

class UV_OT_my_panel(Panel):
    bl_idname = "UV_OT_my_panel"
    bl_label = "My Tool_modify"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"   
    bl_region_type = "TOOLS"    
    bl_category = "Tools"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        scene = context.scene
        mytool = scene.my_tool

        # display the properties
        layout.prop(mytool, "my_bool", text="hide everything")
        layout.prop(mytool, "my_bool1", text="only hide cube")
        layout.prop(mytool, "my_int", text="Integer Property")
        layout.prop(mytool, "my_float", text="Float Property")



# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
# register and unregister functions
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)
    bpy.types.Scene.my_tool = PointerProperty(type=MySettings)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__)
    del bpy.types.Scene.my_tool

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: I know that the printing is working in the console, I want to hide/unhide a Cube in my scene when checking/unchecking the checkbox. As you can see in my script I've tried hiding/unhiding it but it didn't work that's why I commented it. I found the link I provided in my question and tried applying it but it is not working for some reason I don't know.

Comment: @Tak  I update the answere. I think you can continue after this

Answer (score 2):

You have to put a reference to the callback in the update of your property:

```
bl_info = {
"name": "tester",
"description": "",
}

import bpy
from bpy.props import (StringProperty,
                       BoolProperty,
                       IntProperty,
                       FloatProperty,
                       FloatVectorProperty,
                       EnumProperty,
                       PointerProperty,
                       )
from bpy.types import (Panel,
                       Operator,
                       AddonPreferences,
                       PropertyGroup,
                       )

def my_prop_callback(self, context):
    #pass # do something here if user checks checkbox (but not uncheck, just         as an example)
    print("my_prop_callback", repr(self))
    cube = self.id_data.objects.get("Cube")
    if cube:
        cube.hide = not self.my_bool
    return None   

class MySettings(PropertyGroup):

    my_bool = BoolProperty(
        name="Enable or Disable",
        description="A bool property",
        default = False, update=my_prop_callback
        )

class UV_OT_my_panel(Panel):
    bl_idname = "UV_OT_my_panel"
    bl_label = "My Tool"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"   
    bl_region_type = "TOOLS"    
    bl_category = "Tools"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        scene = context.scene
        mytool = scene.my_tool

        # display the properties
        layout.prop(mytool, "my_bool", text="Bool Property")
        #layout.prop(mytool, "my_int", text="Integer Property")
        #layout.prop(mytool, "my_float", text="Float Property")       

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)
    bpy.types.Scene.my_tool = PointerProperty(type=MySettings)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__)
    del bpy.types.Scene.my_tool

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: I'm not sure how I can use my_bool property in the callback?

Comment: No, I mean you never use my_prop in the code, at all, ever. I assume it's supposed to be in your panel, but its still the other properties.

Comment: It does, his property doesn't work because he never uses it in the code.

Comment: What you are saying is not answering my question, if you could please provide an answer to fix my problem