# Loading an image to a texture from a python script file

Tags: python, image

I made a plugin to use on blender, installing the plugin will display a panel, and I wanted to display an image on that panel, so I create a texture in the script file with type 'IMAGE':

```
 ui_tex = bpy.data.textures.new('MP', 'IMAGE')
```

and then when I assign it an image it doesn't seem to load the image:

```
ui_tex.image = bpy.data.images.load("D:/pic.png")
```

So how can I load an image from the script file to a newly created texture.
Note: the previous two python statements are written in a draw function of the panel

Edit: Here is the class for the panel with the draw function:

```
class UIPanel(bpy.types.Panel):

  bl_label = "Label"
  bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
  bl_region_type = "TOOLS"
  br_name = "Printing"

  def draw(self, context):

   layout = self.layout
   scn = context.scene

   ui_tex = bpy.data.textures.new("MP", "IMAGE")
   ui_tex.image = bpy.data.images.load("D:/pic.png")

   row = layout.row(align=True)
   row.alignment = 'EXPAND'
   row.template_preview(bpy.data.textures["MP"])
```

Might I add that I get this error in the blender system console:

```
line 39, in draw
ui_tex.image = bpy.data.images.load(filepath = filepath)
AttributeError: Writing to ID classes in this context is not allowed: MP, Texture datablock, error setting ImageTexture.image
```

Comment: I suggest adding a larger section of your code to the question so we can see how you are going about things currently.

Comment: Okay I did, please find the extra code

Comment: You cannot alter ID object's properties in a draw method.  It's for drawing data to the UI, and runs a lot (a lot) of times per second.  This is by design.  Which for your example above is a good idea otherwise you would be loading and loading and loading the same image over and over.  This would be a handy addition to the [Gotchas](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/info_gotcha.html)

Comment: Related http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43710/how-can-i-change-a-custom-property-value-in-python-attributeerror-writing-to-i?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

Blender v2.79

Load image to texture:

```
bpy.ops.image.open(filepath='full_path_to/your_image.png')
bpy.data.images['your_image.png'].pack(as_png=True) # Pack an image as embedded data into the .blend file
ui_tex.image = bpy.data.images['your_image.png']
```

Don't forget to replace `'full_path_to/your_image.png'` to your own values.

**EDIT:**

I think this method is easier, you simply load the node, given its name and then set the path:

```
im_node = scene.node_tree.nodes["Image"]
im_node.image.filepath = 'full_path_to/your_image.png'
```

Comment: In Blender v2.8 use instead `bpy.data.images['your_image.png'].pack()`