# Unhide objects with UI?

Tags: python, interface

I've been having issues trying to hide an object based off name (as a UI checkbox).

It nearly works, hiding an object is somewhat decent, not perfect as sometimes you need to recheck to work. But the main issue is i can't go back and unhide it.

```
if "bpy" in locals():
    import importlib
    if "MK8_export_paths" in locals():
        importlib.reload(MK8_export_paths)


import bpy
from bpy.types import Operator
from bpy.props import FloatVectorProperty
from bpy_extras.object_utils import AddObjectHelper, object_data_add
from mathutils import Vector
from bl_operators.presets import AddPresetBase

from bpy.props import (StringProperty,
                       BoolProperty,
                       IntProperty,
                       FloatProperty,
                       EnumProperty,
                       PointerProperty,
                       )
from bpy.types import (Panel,
                       AddonPreferences,
                       PropertyGroup,
                       )


def common_update(self, context, origin):

    obj = context.object
    scene = context.scene

    for ob in scene.objects:
        if scene.my_prop:
            if ob.name.startswith("Glide"):
                ob.hide = True
            else:
                ob.unhide = True
    else:
            ob.hide = False         


class MySettings(PropertyGroup):

    bpy.types.Scene.my_prop = bpy.props.BoolProperty(update=lambda self, context: 
    common_update(self, context, 'my_bool_one'))



class PathSETTINGS(Panel):
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_my_panel"
    bl_label = "My Panel"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"   
    bl_region_type = "TOOLS"    
    bl_category = "NewTest"



    def draw(self, context):
        obj = context.object
        layout = self.layout
        scene = context.scene
        layout.label("First row")
        row = layout.row(align=True)
        row.alignment = 'EXPAND'
        row = layout.row()
        row.prop(scene, "my_prop", text="Hide Object")








# Registration


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(MySettings)
    bpy.utils.register_class(PathSETTINGS)
    bpy.types.Scene.my_prop = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=MySettings)



def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MySettings)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(PathSETTINGS)
    del bpy.types.Scene.my_prop




if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: How does `common_update` get called?

Comment: Oh yeah sorry i forgot the part with the boolean when i was copying parts of my script to the site, added it to the top of the code.

Comment: Shouldn't `draw` be indented to be a class method rather than a global function?

Comment: It's apart of the "PathSETTINGS" class, just the indentation seems to have messed up a bit.

Comment: Suggest making script such that it can be run as a working example from blender text editor.   For the formatting required on bse martkup, select all (ctrl-a) , tab (moves all one tab over), copy and paste here.  Also can you explain the reason for `update=lambda self, context: 
common_update(self, context, 'my_bool_one')` instead of simply `update=common_update` and remove the never used origin parameter?

Comment: `if (scene.my_prop == True):` -- please just change that to `if scene.my_prop:`.

Comment: Thanks I updated the code for it to work properly. So "Origin" was just going to be another option for multiple booleans but i ended up not using it. Some of [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43710/how-can-i-change-a-custom-property-value-in-python-attributeerror-writing-to-i) code was used for reference. The `update=lambda self, context: common_update(self, context, ` part just defines those and common update needs 2 arguments.

Comment: If I was to copy the script above and paste in blender, will it run without errors?

Comment: Yup it will. There will then be a new category in the tools tab.

Comment: Please define `bpy.types.Scene.my_prop` and how you are calling update method in register.  On a clean file without the property defined it throws an error.

Comment: Ah yes sorry made a mistake. All that should be fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feel free to try/modify this

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Blank1",
    "author": "Your Name Here",
    "version": (1, 0),
    "blender": (2, 79, 0),
    "location": "View3D > Tools panel 'T' > Blank1 > Blank2",
    "description": "",
    "warning": "",
    "wiki_url": "",
    "category": "",
    }

import bpy
import os
from bpy.types import Operator
from bpy.types import Panel

def unhide_objects(scene):
    """Unhide all objects"""
    for ob in scene.objects:
        ob.hide = False

def ToggleHide(self, context):
    scene = self
    unhide_objects(scene)
    if scene.TestStringProp:
        for ob in scene.objects:
            if ob.name.startswith(str(scene.TestStringProp)):
                ob.hide = True
            else:
                ob.hide = False
    if not scene.TestBool:
        unhide_objects(scene)

def initprop():
    bpy.types.Scene.TestBool = bpy.props.BoolProperty(
        name="TestBool", 
        description="", 
        default=False, 
        subtype='NONE', 
        update=ToggleHide)

    bpy.types.Scene.TestStringProp = bpy.props.StringProperty(
        name="TestStringProp", 
        description="", 
        default="", 
        subtype='NONE')

def delprop():
    del bpy.types.Scene.TestBool
    del bpy.types.Scene.TestStringProp

class VIEW3D_PT_Blank1_Blank2(Panel):
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'TOOLS'
    bl_category = "Blank1"
    bl_context = "objectmode"
    bl_label = "Blank2"

    def draw(self, context):
        scene = context.scene
        layout = self.layout
        row = layout.row()
        col = layout.column(align=True)
        col.label(text="Columns")
        col.prop(scene, "TestBool")
        col.prop(scene, "TestStringProp")

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(VIEW3D_PT_Blank1_Blank2)
    initprop()

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(VIEW3D_PT_Blank1_Blank2)
    delprop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```