# How to manually set selected item in UILayout.template_list?

Tags: python, scripting, panel

I want to select a item from UILayout.template_list from script, not from user interaction. I use following setup:

```
layout.template_list("UI_UL_list", "objects", scene.objectNames, "objects", scene.objectNames, "activeIndex", rows = 1, maxrows=2)
```

I would like to change the active index from script. When I try to do that inside panel's draw-function, I get error:

AttributeError: Writing to ID classes in this context is not allowed: Scene, Scene datablock, error setting activeIndex

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43710/how-can-i-change-a-custom-property-value-in-python-attributeerror-writing-to-i/43727#43727 (possible dupe)  Question title and body appear at odds.

Comment: yeah that looks about right